# Can Laravel Produce a form according to the database model that you have created?

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel but I'm really looking forward to use it and I have one question about what is does?

Can Laravel Produce a form according to the database model that you have created?

e.g. you have a student table which contains: id,std_name,std_class_name as fields. and you are requested to create a form so that you can fill in the information about the student in the database, though you will need a form to do that. Now my question is can Laravel produce that form automatically for you?
that picks the type of the field and produce an according input to it.

for std_name ->

Comment: Check this package it might help you: https://github.com/kristijanhusak/laravel-form-builder

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Laravel can't create a form according to the database model that you have created out of the box. But there is a package that helps you build forms easier. Here is [a link](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html)

Answer (score 0):

No laravel <=5.3 can't autmagicaly create forms directly from db tables. But you can use... [phpmyadmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) :) this tool automagicaly create forms to each table in your db (when you login to db and click on edit/insert row w in your table).